# Junit NetBeans error "No test executed"

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I am running a test case and after running it I receive the result saying "No test executed"
 while it shows the result as passed.

Underneath the "No Test Executed" leyend, you the name of the test class can be seen with the status "passed" (on the
right side). If I try to open the tree node, it doesn't show what tests were executed (the tree is empty).

Does anybody know why I receive this message? I am using Junit version 4

Here is the test sample

```
 @Test
 public void myTester() throws Exception{
      Myclass tester = new Myclass() {
          @Override
          public int multiply(int 1 , int j){
           return i*j;
           }
      };
      assertEqual(50, multiply(5,10));
 }
```

Comment: What version of JUnit are you running? Where's your test-case code?

Comment: Are you using Maven? I have seen similar issues with a few specific versions of the [`surefire-maven-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/), so you might want to try upgrading to the latest version (or downgrading if you're already at the latest).

Comment: I don't have Netbeans installed right now, but I could assume that the test could have @Ignore annotation?

Comment: The ignore annotation was at the top of the class. I missed it

Comment: The method myTester seems ok, if your assert if `assertEqual(50, tester.multiply(5,10));` instead of simply `multiply(5,10)`. But did you first try to ask Netbeans to generate a Junit4 test for you (from any of you classes) and ensure your test class is declared the same way ?

Comment: The test case for the project was already there, so I added my part manually.